# Long polling blocking multiple windows?

Tags: long-polling

Long polling has solved 99% of my problems. There is now just one other problem. Imagine a penny auction site, where people bid. On the frontpage, there are several Auctions.

If the user opens three of these auctions, and because javascript is not multithreaded, how would you get the other pages to ever load? Won't they always get bogged down and not load because they are waiting for long polling to end? In practice, I've experienced this and I can't think of a way around it. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to set up a specific polling server so you don't run into connection limit issues and look into script tag polling. Not saying it is an answer, but it may help you get around the problems you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that javascript gets around some of this.

1. While javascript is single threaded conceptually, it does its io in separate threads using completion handlers. This means other pieces of javascript can be running while you are waiting for your network request to complete.
2. Javascript for each page (or even each frame in each page) is isolated from Javascript on the other pages/frames. This means that each copy of javascript can be running in its own thread.

A bigger issue for you is likely to be that browsers often limit the number of concurrent connections to a given site, and it sounds like you want to make many concurrent connections to the same site.  In this case you will get a lock up.

If you control both the sever and client, you will need to combined the multiple long-poll request from the client into a single long-poll request to the server.